# how to make an emit works instantly in laravel 9 vuejs 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

I'm trying to get familiar with laravel9, vuejs3 and vite with a simple ecommerce website
the problem is when I click add to carte its work fine but the count in icon carte incrementing but till I reload the page.
this my add to carte component

```
<template>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-4">
        <button
            class=" bg-orange-700 text-black rounded-md cursor-pointer text-xs font-semibold px-3 py-2 m-4 "
            v-on:click.prevent="addToCart"
        >
            Ajouter au panier
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup >
import useProduct from '../composables/products'
import axios from 'axios';
import Emitter from 'pico-emitter';


    const {add} = useProduct()
    const productId = defineProps(['productId'])


    const emitter = new Emitter();
    
    const addToCart= async()=>{
        await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
                await axios.get('/api/user')
                .then(async(res)=>{
                    let cartCount= await add(productId);
                    emitter.emit('refreshCartCount',cartCount);
                    console.log(cartCount)
                })
                .catch(err=>console.log(err));

    }

</script>
```

and navbare cart component I used tiny-emitter but it doesn't worked correctly so I tied a similar package pico-emitter

```
    <template>
        <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex mr-10">
        <a href="/shoppingCart" class="relative">
            <span class="absolute -top-1 left-4 rounded-full bg-indigo-700 w-5 h-5 text-xs text-white flex items-center justify-center">{{ cartCount }}</span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-7 w-7 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-600 " fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16 11V7a4 4 0 00-8 0v4M5 9h14l1 12H4L5 9z" />
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import Emitter from 'pico-emitter';
import {onMounted,ref} from 'vue';
import useProduct from '../composables/products'; 


const {getCount}= useProduct();
const cartCount=ref(0)

const emitter = new Emitter();

emitter.on('refreshCartCount',function(count){
    cartCount.value = count
});


onMounted(async()=>{

 cartCount.value = await getCount();
   
     console.log(cartCount.value)

});

</script>
```

and the index file

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function useProduct(){
    const add = async(productId)=>{
        let response = await axios.post('/api/products',{  
            productId: productId
            
    });
    return response.data.count;
    }

        const getCount = async() =>{

            let response = await axios.get('/api/products/count');

            return response.data.count;
        }





    return {
        add,
        getCount
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple instances of the Emitter won't work. The events are contained within one instance of Emitter.

You could write a simple [plugin](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#writing-a-plugin) that makes the pico-emitter available as a global property, or just make it a global property.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Emitter from 'pico-emitter';
const emitter = new Emitter();
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
app.mount('#app');
```

Then in your component you can use `this.emitter.emit()` and `this.emitter.on()`